# Unable to make form in Django

Tags: python, django

I have recently started making a Django web app for a personal project of mine. I have made a model, and `makemigrations` / `migrate` works fine. When I made the form, and ran those commands, I received the following error: `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (mideals) specified for Sheet`.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from . import models

class CreateSheet(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Sheet
        fields = [
            'name', 'slug', 'Class', 'background', 'race', 'xp', 'level',
            'strength', 'dexterity', 'constitution', 'intelligence', 'wisdom',
            'charisma', 'strengthMod', 'dexterityMod', 'constitutionMod',
            'intelligenceMod', 'wisdomMod', 'charismaMod', 'sStrength',
            'sDexterity', 'sConstitution', 'sIntelligence', 'sWisdom',
            'sCharisma', 'acrobatics', 'animalHandling', 'arcana', 'athletics',
            'deception', 'history', 'insight', 'intimidation', 'investigation',
            'medicine', 'nature', 'perception', 'performance', 'persuasion',
            'religion', 'sleightOfHand', 'stealth', 'survival',
            'acrobaticsMod', 'animalHandlingMod', 'arcanaMod', 'deceptionMod',
            'historyMod', 'insightMod', 'intimidationMod', 'investigationMod',
            'medicineMod', 'natureMod', 'perceptionMod', 'performanceMod',
            'persuasionMod', 'religionMod', 'sleightOfHandMod', 'stealthMod',
            'survivalMod', 'otherProficiencies', 'languages', 'equipment',
            'copper', 'silver', 'gold', 'platinum', 'armorClass', 'initiative',
            'speed', 'maxHitPoints', 'hitPoints', 'hitDice', 'sDeathSave1',
            'sDeathSave2', 'sDeathSave3', 'fDeathSave1', 'fDeathSave2',
            'fDeathSave3', 'personalityTraits', 'mideals', 'bonds', 'flaws',
            'featuresTraits',
        ]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Sheet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(default="")

    Class = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    background = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    race = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    xp = models.IntegerField()
    level = models.IntegerField()

    strength = models.IntegerField()
    dexterity = models.IntegerField()
    constitution = models.IntegerField()
    intelligence = models.IntegerField()
    wisdom = models.IntegerField()
    charisma = models.IntegerField()

    strengthMod = models.IntegerField()
    dexterityMod = models.IntegerField()
    constitutionMod = models.IntegerField()
    intelligenceMod = models.IntegerField()
    wisdomMod = models.IntegerField()
    charismaMod = models.IntegerField()

    sStrength = models.BooleanField()
    sDexterity = models.BooleanField()
    sConstitution = models.BooleanField()
    sIntelligence = models.BooleanField()
    sWisdom = models.BooleanField()
    sCharisma = models.BooleanField()

    acrobatics = models.BooleanField()
    animalHandling = models.BooleanField()
    arcana = models.BooleanField()
    athletics = models.BooleanField()
    deception = models.BooleanField()
    history = models.BooleanField()
    insight = models.BooleanField()
    intimidation = models.BooleanField()
    investigation = models.BooleanField()
    medicine = models.BooleanField()
    nature = models.BooleanField()
    perception = models.BooleanField()
    performance = models.BooleanField()
    persuasion = models.BooleanField()
    religion = models.BooleanField()
    sleightOfHand = models.BooleanField()
    stealth = models.BooleanField()
    survival = models.BooleanField()

    acrobaticsMod = models.IntegerField()
    animalHandlingMod = models.IntegerField()
    arcanaMod = models.IntegerField()
    deceptionMod = models.IntegerField()
    historyMod = models.IntegerField()
    insightMod = models.IntegerField()
    intimidationMod = models.IntegerField()
    investigationMod = models.IntegerField()
    medicineMod = models.IntegerField()
    natureMod = models.IntegerField()
    perceptionMod = models.IntegerField()
    performanceMod = models.IntegerField()
    persuasionMod = models.IntegerField()
    religionMod = models.IntegerField()
    sleightOfHandMod = models.IntegerField()
    stealthMod = models.IntegerField()
    survivalMod = models.IntegerField()

    otherProficiencies = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    languages = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    equipment = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    copper = models.IntegerField()
    silver = models.IntegerField()
    gold = models.IntegerField()
    platinum = models.IntegerField()

    armorClass = models.IntegerField()
    initiative = models.IntegerField()
    speed = models.IntegerField()
    maxHitPoints = models.IntegerField()
    hitPoints = models.IntegerField()
    hitDice = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    sDeathSave1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sDeathSave2 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sDeathSave3 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    fDeathSave1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    fDeathSave2 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    fDeathSave3 = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    personalityTraits = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    ideals = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    bonds = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    flaws = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    featuresTraits = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I really have no idea what's going on here. I've looked on stack overflow and there seems to be almost nothing related to my error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the error is perfectly clear, you've specified a field, `mideals` that isn't in your model. Looks like it might be a typo for `ideals`?. (But holy ****, it's painful to have a model with so many fields, and then include them individually by name in your form. At the very least use the [__all__](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use) shorthand. Or `exclude` if there are a few you don't want.)

Comment: Honestly, this is the longest model I've seen ever :D.. Anyway, it's just because your model doesn't have field name which you put inside fields property of your form - `mideals`. Remove it if your model don't have that field or add it into your model if you think you really need it

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed it, and also I did not know about the all shorthand and that is extremely useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifying that you want the field `mideals` to be included in the form, but that field doesn't exist on the `Sheet` model. You should remove that field from the list of fields on the form or add it to the model.

If you want all the fields from the model to appear on the form it would be better to use `fields = '__all__'`